# Android - Checkbox repeating every 10th in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

Hello I've been trying to create a listview with a custom adapter to put two textviews and one checkbox in it. The listviews work fine but the checkboxes start to repeat every 10th so if you check the first checkbox the 10th one also checks and so on. I did research about this but couldn't find a specific answer that was well explained that I could understand what exactly I had to do to fix it. So how do I fix the checkboxes so that they dont repeat?

act_view_items_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/workout_items_textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/workout_items_textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/workout_items_textView2"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/workout_items_textView2"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/workout_items_CheckBox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:height="50dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/workout_items_CheckBox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workout_items_textView2"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_items.java

```
public class view_items extends ListActivity {
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter2;
    private TaskDBHelper helper;
    private TextView taskTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_view_items);

        updateUI2();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Add a Workout");
                builder.setMessage("Enter the name of the workout");
                final EditText inputField = new EditText(this);
                builder.setView(inputField);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(view_items.this);
                        builder2.setTitle("Add a Workout");
                        builder2.setMessage("Enter the reps for the workout");
                        final EditText inputField2 = new EditText(view_items.this);
                        builder2.setView(inputField2);
                        builder2.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                String task = inputField.getText().toString();
                                String reps = inputField2.getText().toString();
                                String workoutID = TaskContract.UNSTABLE_WORKOUT_ID;

                                helper = new TaskDBHelper(view_items.this);
                                SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                                values.clear();
                                values.put(TaskContract.Columns.TASK, task);
                                values.put(TaskContract.Columns.REPS, reps);
                                values.put(TaskContract.Columns.WORKOUT_ID, workoutID);

                                db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                                updateUI2();
                            }


                        });
                        builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                        builder2.create().show();

                    }


                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

                builder.create().show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }


    public void updateUI2(){

        // TodoDatabaseHandler is a SQLiteOpenHelper class connecting to SQLite
        TaskDBHelper handler = new TaskDBHelper(this);
        // Get access to the underlying writeable database
        SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
        // Query for items from the database and get a cursor back
        String sql2 = String.format("SELECT  * FROM workout_items WHERE %s = '%s'",
                TaskContract.Columns.WORKOUT_ID,
                TaskContract.UNSTABLE_WORKOUT_ID);


        Cursor todoCursor = db.rawQuery(sql2, null);

        // Find ListView to populate
        setContentView(R.layout.act_view_items);
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        // Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        view_items_CursorAdapter todoAdapter = new view_items_CursorAdapter(this, todoCursor, 0);
        // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);




    }

    public void onDoneButtonClick(View view) {
        View v = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
        String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();

        String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
                TaskContract.TABLE,
                TaskContract.Columns.TASK,
                task);


        helper = new TaskDBHelper(view_items.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
        updateUI2();
    }

}
```

view_items_CursorAdapter.java

```
public class view_items_CursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public view_items_CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.act_view_items_view, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


        TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.workout_items_textView);
        TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.workout_items_textView2);

        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("task"));
        int priority = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("reps"));

        tvBody.setText(body);
        tvPriority.setText(String.valueOf(priority));
    }



}
```

Comment: I'd guess this is happening because your adapter recycles views, which means it reuses an already rendered view. To achieve the best result, you need to also set the checked state of your checkbox on your `bindView` method the same way you do with the `TextView`s

Comment: Could I possibly save the state of the checkboxes to a sql database and then set their status on the bindview method just like with the textviews or would that not be efficient?

Comment: If the checked state is something you think should be always available, then I don't see why not. But you'll probably want to clear it when the app is closed, otherwise the checked state will be kept across sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
 public class view_items_CursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
 boolean[] checkbox;
 public view_items_CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags)      
{
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    checkbox = new boolean[cursor.getCount()];
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.act_view_items_view, parent, false);
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final int position = cursor.getPosition();
    TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.workout_items_textView);
    TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.workout_items_textView2);
    CheckBox tvCheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);

    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("task"));
    int priority = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("reps"));

    tvBody.setText(body);
    tvPriority.setText(String.valueOf(priority));
    tvCheck.setChecked(checkbox[position]);
    tvCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         checkbox[position] = isChecked;
       }});
}
```

Comment: Well it doesnt repeat but it resets the checkboxes to not checked after you scroll through the listview.

Comment: Ok so I modified the code a bit and it seems to work perfectly now. Thanks for the great example it let me understand the whole method a lot better.